# JQuery scrollTop() function not scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to scroll to an element after clicking on a link in the navigation bar. I looked up how to do this using JQuery's scrollTop() function, and using resources from stack overflow, i came up with this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sib Quayum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" class="clickContact">Contact </a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="clickAbout">About Me </a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="clickHome">Home </a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div class="headerBreak"></div>

<br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>

<div id="About">Hi this is about me.</div>


<br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br>

<div id="Contact">Contact me and stuff</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".clickContact").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#Contact').offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

CSS:

```
*{
    font-family:Tahoma;
}

.nav{


    height:40px;
    background:maroon;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.nav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.nav ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

.nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:orange;
}

.nav ul li a:hover{
    color:white;
}
```

Whenever I click on "Contact" on the navigation menu, it does not scroll the #Contact div.  I am new to HTML/CSS/Javascript, any help would be appreciated.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9g18ecgs/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the page reloads when you click on the links. Try to replace this

```
.nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:orange;
}

By this :

.nav ul li{
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:orange;
    cursor: pointer;
}


And this :


<li><a href="" class="clickContact">Contact </a></li>
<li><a href="" class="clickAbout">About Me </a></li>
<li><a href="" class="clickHome">Home </a></li>


By this :


<li class="clickContact">Contact</li>
<li class="clickAbout">About Me</li>
<li class="clickHome">Home</li>
```

It'll work !! http://jsfiddle.net/9g18ecgs/4/

Comment: The JSfiddle seems to work fine, but when I put it in my code, and runt he website in a browser(Chrome) it doesn't work. I click on contact and nothing happens. I tried copy pasting your JSfiddle code directly and it didnt work either.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine if you just add `return false` to your event handler:

```
$(".clickContact").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#Contact').offset().top }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n9n43on7/

Comment: The same thing is happening with your solution as with Idov Mamane's solution. The JSFiddle works, but when I put it in my HTML/CSS/JS files and run it in Chrome, nothing changes.

Comment: @sqsib I notice your script is included using a script tag - are you sure the script is being loaded?  Make sure the script is in the correct location with the correct filename.  Also check your JavaScript console to see if you have any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide href attribute to the anchor you are clicking on, because it is not there page is scrolling back to top.

```
<a href="#Contact" class="clickContact">Contact </a>
```

Please refer updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9g18ecgs/1/

Comment: Anchor tags do not require a `href` attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href

Comment: Yes, you are right but in this context it is needed. BTW your solution is also good way out

Comment: When i added the attribute, it didn't scroll, it just jumped to it.

Comment: no way, Pleaser refer the fiddle and its working solution. Can you please update your question with updated changes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of jquery you just simply need to use :

```
<li><a href="#contact" class="clickContact">Contact </a></li>
```

To goto contact div position. Check out snippet code

```css
*{
    font-family:Tahoma;
}

.nav{


    height:40px;
    background:maroon;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.nav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.nav ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

.nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:orange;
}

.nav ul li a:hover{
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sib Quayum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="clickContact">Contact </a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="clickAbout">About Me </a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="clickHome">Home </a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div class="headerBreak"></div>

<br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>

<div id="About">Hi this is about me.</div>


<br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<br>

<div id="Contact">Contact me and stuff</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was trying to make it animate, so that's why I wanted to use JQuery.